# Which changes faster $ f(m) = {n \choose m}$ or $ g(m) = n^{-2c \frac{mn - m^2}{n-1}}$ wrt $m$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have two functions of $m$. $m$ and $n$ are both integers with $m <n$.

The functions are :-
$$ f(m) = {n \choose m}$$ and

## $$ g(m) = n^{-2c \frac{mn - m^2}{n-1}}$$

$c$ is a constant which you may take to be 1.

I wish to show that as $m$ varies from $1$ to $n/2$ , $g(m)$ decreases at a faster rate than $f(m)$ grows. (My goal is to show that f(1)g(1)) is a maxima. )

To do so I am trying to find the derivative of the two . The derivative which is larger in magnitude will indicate a greater rate of change. Is my approach correct ? I am unable to find a derivative for $f(m)$. I was thinking of bounding the binomial coefficient too.

Also $n$ is very large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use logarithms. Considering that $n\gg1$, we have (using Stirling's approximation) $$\ln f(m)=n\ln n-m\ln m-(n-m)\ln(n-m)+O(\ln m)$$
and
$$\ln g(m)=-2c\ln n\frac{mn-m^2}{n-1}.$$
The derivatives with respect to $m$ are
$$\frac{\mathrm d\ln f}{\mathrm dm}=\ln\frac{n-m}m+O(1),\qquad
\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln f}{\mathrm dm^2}=-\frac{n}{m(n-m)}+O(1)$$
$$\frac{\mathrm d\ln g}{\mathrm dm}=-2c\ln n\;\frac{n-2m}{n-1},\qquad
\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln g}{\mathrm dm^2}=4c\frac{\ln n}{n-1}.$$
Then you see that
$$\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln(fg)}{\mathrm dm^2}=\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln g}{\mathrm dm^2}+\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln g}{\mathrm dm^2}$$
cancels for $m=m_0$ of the order of $-1/(4c\ln n)$. ( **EDIT** I made a mistake in my original answer. The value of $m_0$ is the one that is here now.)
It follows that $\frac{\mathrm d^2\ln(fg)}{\mathrm dm^2}$ is positive for $m>0$. Since $\frac{\mathrm d\ln(fg)}{\mathrm dm}=0$ for $m=n/2$, it means that $\frac{\mathrm d\ln(fg)}{\mathrm dm}\leq0$ for $0\leq m\leq n/2$ and then that your claim is correct : $fg$ is maximum for $m=1$ (actually for $m=0$, but you seem to omit this value.)

Comment: I did not understand the motivation behind calculating the higher order derivatives . I thought the first derivatives would suffice?

Comment: I have edited my answer (I made a kind of typo mistake that had strong consequences). I still use the second order derivative to find the sign of the first order derivative. Sometimes it is useful to go one step beyond, because, as in this case, it made things **a lot** simpler : it got rid of the logs !